# Short Date from text field into sql statement ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

```
strSQLzm1a = "INSERT INTO dbGrafikTest (imieNazwisko, numerTelefonu, zmiana, praca, data) VALUES ('" & Me!listZM1a.Column(0) & "', '" & Me!listZM1a.Column(1) & "', 'zm1', 'automatyk', #" & Me!txtData & "#);"
```

This SQL statement returns error:

> Syntax error in date in query expression '#21.03.2016'.

`txtData` is a `text field` and its formated as `Short Date`.
I'm searching googles to find the answer for where i made a syntax error and i really dont understand where i did it.

Database column `data` is formated as `Date/Time` as well.

Comment: You've got a `#` at the end of your insert statement. Is that deliberate?

Comment: I'm not obligated to put `#` at the begining and at the end of the 'object' to determinate its date field?

Comment: Ah - Just spotted it's Access, so I don't know the answer to that, but it does appear that the leading `#` might be an issue. What happens if you miss it out?

Comment: if i delete them i get no error, but nothing is inserted into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db engine can't cope with `21.03.2016` as a date literal.

`Format` it in a way which the db engine can use.

Change this ...

```vb
& Me!txtData &
```

to this ...

```
& Format(Me!txtData, "yyyy-m-d") &
```

Or you could use a parameter query, and then supply the needed Date/Time value without format concerns.

Comment: Thank You, something new to learn. That fixed my issue. I assumed that if I will format everything as date then there wont be any formatting needed in SQL statement.